# Get individual characters from string assembly x86_64

Tags: string, assembly, character, x86-64

Firstly, a bit of background: I'm using x86_64 Assembly with AT&T syntax and compiling with the GCC compiler.
I've been doing assembly for a grand total of a few weeks but this extremely simple problem has me completely stumped:
All i want to do is access individual characters in a string. In any other language I know, this would simply be a matter of doing this (C++):

```
string testString = "ABCDEFG";
char testChar = testString[0];  // and now I would have my character in testChar so i can work with it further
```

I am aware that strings are just arrays of characters, so i tried doing this:

```
.text
testString: .asciz "ABCDEFG"

.global main

main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    leaq testString, %rbx

    addq $1, %rbx

    movq %rbx, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call printf

    movq $0, %rdi
    call exit
```

I am putting the address of the string into RBX and incrementing it. However, because the value of RBX is just a pointer to the start of the string, when I increment it i just get a pointer to the second character of the string. Because of that, my output is simply

```
BCDEFG
```

I've tried google, youtube, Quora, etc. but I can't seem to find a simple answer to this apparently dumb question.
So: how would I go about getting the actual value of a character out of the string, so that I can work with it in my code?

Thanks a lot in advance!
- Vlad

Comment: Yes that is correct, and that is exactly what the C code would also do since you have written `printf(testString + 1);`. You have the address in `rbx` you can then load the character and do whatever you want with it. Unfortunately you haven't specified what you want but it could be as simple as `movb (%rbx), %al`. Obviously that can also be written as `movb testString+1, %al` if you don't want to mess with the pointers. PS: note of course that's not `testString[0]`, it's `testString[1]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to work. One last question: trying to move this value out of ```%al``` and into a large register such as ```%rsi``` gives me a segmentation fault. I tried to use ```movzx %al, %rsi``` to zero-extend it to the right size, but that doesn't seem to help. I'm trying to move it to %RSI so that i can print it with printf

Comment: `printf` expects a pointer to a string. You can't pass a char to it. You have attempted to do `printf((char*)testString[1]);` which would crash in C too. To print a char you either convert it to a string, or use a format string such as `"%c"` and pass your char as an additional argument.

Comment: Obviously you can also just use `putchar` instead of `printf`.